# warning: implicit declaration of function `timerisset'

Tags: c, centos

Moving from an older CentOS server to a newer one with the same GCC version results in an error compiling C code that did not occur on the old server:

```
interp.c: In function `update_userec':
interp.c:1100: warning: implicit declaration of function `timerisset'
interp.c:1101: warning: implicit declaration of function `timercmp'
interp.c:1101: error: syntax error before '<' token
```

Code:

```
if ( !timerisset(&userec->min_time)
||    timercmp(time_used, &userec->min_time, <) )
{
```

This file does indeed have at the top of file:

```
#include <time.h>
```

gcc version:

```
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-languages=c,c++,f77 --disable-libgcj --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-19.el6)
```

The man page does mention:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    All functions shown above:
>        Since glibc 2.19:
>            _DEFAULT_SOURCE
>        Glibc 2.19 and earlier:
>            _BSD_SOURCE
> ```

But defining `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` or `_BSD_SOURCE` above the `include` line does not resolve anything.

Comment: Your GCC is awfully old. Consider updating it. Current one is [GCC 8.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/). Prefer a recent GCC to an ancient one (i.e. moving to a more recent Linux distro and keeping an ancient GCC is a mistake). Also, be sure to use a recent Glibc. Current one is [Glibc 2.28](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html). Use on your new server the default system `gcc` and `libc6`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There is already a modern gcc installed, this is an alt install for MUDs. There are no plans to remove the old version as many MUDs are from 1994 and won't be able to compile.

Comment: What does MUD mean? This [MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes.